# How to logout my yahoo account by clearing the browser history or cache when back button click

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, yahoo, browser-cache

I have used Yahoo API in my application to get yahoo mail contacts, I need to logout the yahoo account when user click back button from my browser. How to accomplish this by JavaScript or C#?

Comment: From where do you log in to yahoo, the browser or the server? Clearing a browser cache is impossible from a server and will not log you out: usually **cookies** are used for that. Please explain some more: how/where did you log in? What did you try to log out, where are you stuck?

Comment: I login from server using url like this to get https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token to get token, http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/ to access email contacts and get email contacts in xml